# SimpleXML iteration only outputs first child element

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I have an XML feed that I want to loop through and display all it's child elements, but for some reason I can only output the first,

Feed -

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [title] => Lorem Ipsum
    [description] => Overall description
    [link] => http://someurl.com
    [pubDate] => Thu, 17 Jul 2014 10:49:09 +0000
    [ttl] => 123
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => Lorem Ipsum Dolor 2
                    [link] => http://someurl.com
                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [pubDate] => Thu, 17 Jul 2014 10:49:09 +0000
                    [guid] => http://www.someurl.com
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => Lorem Ipsum Dolor 1
                    [link] => http://someurl.com
                    [description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [pubDate] => Thu, 17 Jul 2014 10:24:51 +0000
                    [guid] => http://someurl.com
                )
          ETC
  )
)
```

PHP -

```
$entries = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->item->description;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't affect the structure of the feed, so I need to somehow be able to iterate down and start my loop at the item element. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML may seem like magic, but it's not so magic that you don't have to adapt it to match the XML you're reading.

Your question contains the germ of its own answer here:

> Unfortunately I can't affect the structure of the feed, so I need to somehow be able to iterate down and start my loop at the item element. Ideas?

What you are looking for is nothing more complex than a *nested loop*: from what you described (and there's not much detail in the question) you have multiple "entries", each containing multiple "items". So within your existing loop over entries, you need another `foreach` loop to access each `item` in turn.

```
$entries = simplexml_load_file($feed);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry->item as $item) {
        echo $item->description;
    }
}
```

Note that where you had `$entry->item->description`, this was returning the first node; SimpleXML had allowed you to write it as shorthand for `$entry->item[0]->description` - i.e. the *first* child with that name. Now that it's being *iterated*, `$entry->item` will instead refer to the list of all children with that name, each of which will be assigned to `$item` in turn.

Comment: That got it working, thanks! And great explanation too.